# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ecommerce.mvc/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm using SPRING MVC to create a Hello world application, this error Appears when i run the application on tomcat server.
I've seen a lot of similar questions being asked, but none of the suggestions worked for me.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eheio.spring.ecommerce.mvc.controller" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.eheio.spring.ecommerce.mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("ssss");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world !!
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.eheio.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce.mvc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce.mvc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ecommerce.mvc</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

The URL that gives me the error is  localhost:8080/ecommerce.mvc/
ecommerce.mvc is the name of my project
Any ideas? thank you for your helps!

Comment: What's your full URL you accessed that give error?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn http://localhost:8080/ecommerce.mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one mapping is `/`,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and you have only one mapping at controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

So either you access your server with `localhost:8080` only or change the request mapping to `@RequestMapping("/ecommerce.mvc")`

**Note** that you're mixing `@Annotation` with `XML` config style.

You'd better stick to only one config style. And `@Annotation` is prefered.

But for educational purpose you should try XML too.

Your mapping config is wrong:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This mapping want a `dispatcher` servlet name.

But the dispatcher is configured wrong:

```
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

The `servlet-class` should be configured by your `HomeController` path

Comment: I tried them both, same error ! by the way ecommerce.mvc is the name of my project.

Comment: Do you running on tomcat? or embeded tomcat?

Comment: running on tomcat .

Comment: `<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>`
Change this to  `<servlet-class>com.eheio.spring.ecommerce.mvc.controller.HomeController</servlet-class>`